# on duplicate key update id=last_insert_id(id) - did the INSERT actually happen?

Tags: mysql, last-insert-id

I need to INSERT a new row into my TABLE(with unique field 'A'), if it already exists(duplicate field, insert failed) - just return the ID of the existing one.

This code works well:

```
insert into TABLE set A=1 on duplicate key update id=last_insert_id(id)
```

But now I have another problem: how do I know if the returning ID belongs to a new (inserted) row or it's just an old one?

Yes, I can do "SELECT id WHERE A=1" beforehand, but it would overcomplicate the program code, require two steps, and just looks ugly. Besides, in future I may want to remove some UNIQUE indexes, then I'll have to rewrite the program as well to change all the 'where' checks. Maybe there is a better solution?

[solved, see my answer]

Comment: I can't think of a way you'd know that. If that is a requirement, execute two queries: `select count(*) from table where id = 1`. If your count is not zero, ID exists. If count is zero, execute your insert and you'll know the id is from the newly inserted record.

Comment: I think u wanted to say "where A=1", but I got your idea. Yes, of course it works, but what if there are multiple unique fields in my table - then I'll have to build a really big and ugly (well, as ugly as the INSERT one) SELECT query to check this.  Like "where A=1 or B=2 or C=3" - that would look ugly in the actual program. Thanks for the answer though

Comment: Yeah, your query could be long if you have those kinds of checks. You are on the right track already.

Comment: You can't `"return"` a value from an `INSERT` query. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Nick, I'm trying to INSERT a new row or get the ID of the existing one (if it duplicates). [It's already solved]. But when I get this ID, how do I know if it's a newly created ID (by INSERT) or the existed one (from UPDATE)

Comment: Gotcha. In that case, I think you're stuck with a `SELECT` beforehand; at least if you do that you can then avoid the `INSERT` if it's not required. Another alternative might be to `SELECT MAX(id) FROM table` and check if it's less than or equal to that (which would indicate that it is an old value)

Comment: Nick, with all respect, please read the comments before writing new ones. Yes, it works and could be a solution, but it's really ugly. By the way, I think I fould the good one (answered my own question), it should work for everyone

Comment: What you're doing doesn't make sense. Updating the ID of an existing row just because it already existed is surely going to break everything.

Comment: Marquis, it definetly does make sense and surely will not break anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this solution. It works in console, but doesn't work in my program (must be a bug in the client, idk) - so probably it will work fine for everyone (except me, sigh)

Just check the 'affected rows count' - it will be 1 for the new record and 0 for the old one

```
mysql> INSERT INTO EMAIL set addr="test" ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)<----- 1 = INSERTed

mysql> select last_insert_id(); //returns 1

mysql> INSERT INTO EMAIL set addr="test" ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec) <----- 0 = OLD

mysql> select last_insert_id(); //returns 1
```

UPD: it didn't work for me because my program kept sending the 'CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS ' flag when connecting to mysql. Removed it, now everything is fine!